# Displaying only one div from an external website using iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe

is there any way I could pull only a portion of an external website using iframe?

This is the page I am trying to pull..
http://clep.collegeboard.org/search/test-centers

The div I wanted to get specifically is the white box in the center (#mainContentWrapper).

I already have a solution myself although it has some flaws. The trick I made was I made an outer div and disabled the iframe and I tweaked the height/width and the positioning where it would only show that portion ...

```
#outeriframe
{
   width:960px;
   height:1415px;
   overflow:hidden;
   position:relative;
}

#inneriframe
{
   position:absolute;
   top:-300px;
   left:-160px;
   width:1280px;
   height:1415px;
}
```

The problem is, if the iframe is too big, the footer would show up, if it's too short, the results would be cut off and you can't see them all...

Is there any way I could get around this? Maybe Hide the footer? or grab only the Div I need? Please help me...

Thanks!

Comment: Could you use something like php to screen scrape the data?

Comment: I could, but I'm actually looking to use their search feature.. I can't seem to do that if I use php.. If you are talking about  file_get_contents

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the same origin policy forbids you to interact with a Web page located in a different domain.

Some techniques like CORS or postMessage allow you to work around this limitation, but require some level of control on the other domain.

Comment: Thanks, but there's gotta be some trick to at least mask the other divs in some way..

Comment: but like i said, whenever the content changes, the height also does, if it becomes too short, it'll show some parts of the footer..

Comment: Right. The same origin policy protects the user from malicious attacks, and prevents you from taking others' page content and pretending it's your own. As I said in the answer, there are "tricks", but they require some cooperation from the remote site.